# Is there any way to exclude implicit time convertions in org.spec2.time and use your own?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, specs2

I'm trying to use specs2, and I have a problem with implicit conversions which are blended with those imported by me from scala.concurrent.duration._, is there any way to exclude implicite conversions from the scope?

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class StatisticsSampleCacheSpec extends Specification {

    val map: Map[Long, Duration] = Map(
        1L -> 5.minute,
        3L -> 3.day,
        5L -> 5.day,
        7L -> 30.day)
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's quite common problem, try to mix-in [`org.specs2.time.NoTimeConversions`](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/api/SPECS2-2.1.1/index.html#org.specs2.time.NoTimeConversions) trait:

```
class StatisticsSampleCacheSpec extends Specification with NoTimeConversions
```